# Links in Apple Wallet pass not interactive

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit, apple-wallet, pkpass

I have a Apple Wallet Pass with a back field declared like so:

```json
{
  key: 'EnableLink',
  label: 'Powered by',
  value: 'Enable.tech',
  attributedValue: "<a href='https://enable.tech'>Enable.tech</a>"
}
```

When the wallet pass is active (side button pressed twice), and the user goes to the back of the pass, the link is visible and highlighted, however tapping it does not open the linked webpage in a browser. There are `tel:` links that cannot be interacted with as well.

I've tried moving the anchor tags to the `value` field and removing the attributedValue field, but that didn't seem to make any difference either.

Here's a [sample Apple Wallet pass.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjftG.png)

Notice that the links on the back of the pass, such as "Enable.tech", "Claim Discount by Phone", and "Claim Discount by WhatsApp" cannot be tapped when the pass is active.

Anyone know a workaround or a fix?